# An exercise: using Gronwal's Inequality to prove a function is zero

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following version of Gronwal's inequality, as in Verhulst's "Nonlinear Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems":

Assume that $t_0\leq t \leq t_0+a$, $\delta_1,\delta_3$ are positive constants,$\phi(t),\psi(t)$ are continuous, non-negative functions. Assume
$$
\phi(t) \leq \delta_1 \int_{t_0}^t \psi(s)\phi(s)ds + \delta_3.
$$

Then
$$
\phi(t) \leq \delta_3 e^{\delta_1 \int_{t_0}^t \psi(s)ds}
$$
for $t_0\leq t \leq t_0+a$.

The book remarks that, when $\delta_3=0$, then one can use the estimate on the hypothesis to proof that $\phi(t)=0$. It's left as an unmarked exercise. I've tried to prove so but couldn't; rewriting the proof didn't lead me nowhere. Would someone be able to give me a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you've assumed that $\phi(t)\geq 0$ and you further have that $\phi(t)\leq \delta_3 e^{\delta_1\int_{t_0}^t \psi(s)ds}$ where $\delta_3=0$, then you have $\phi(t)\leq 0$. But all in all, that says that $\phi(t)\equiv 0$.

Comment: I don't think you ca just plug $\delta_3=0$ because the inequality is proved assuming $\delta_3> 0$.

Comment: Given any $\epsilon \gt 0$, you can pick $\delta_3$ such that the RHS is less than $\epsilon$, which implies that $\phi(t)\le 0$